# Develop an algorithm for "The Tumbler Problem"

Tags: algorithm

Problem Statement: Several tumblers are placed in a line on a table. Some tumblers are upside down, some are the right way up. It is required to turn all the tumblers the right way up. However, the tumblers may not be turned individually; an allowed move is to turn any two tumbler simultaneously. From which initial states of the tumblers is it possible to turn all the tumblers the right way up?

I need to understand the problem and develop an algorithm for this problem

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? What have you tried?

Comment: This is a classic and I'd advise you to do some own research before asking this on stackoverflow. The solution is furthermore not that hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tumblers start either upside-down or rightside-up, think of it in binary - each tumbler is a bit: correct orientation = 0, incorrect = 1. Thus, when you have finished the problem, the sum will be 0 (all 0's).

Also note that there are 3 possible moves if you have to do 2 at a time:

- flip a 1 into a 0 and a 0 into a 1 (net change is -1 + 1 = 0)
- flip two 0's into 1's (net change is 1 + 1 = 2)
- flip two 1's into 0's (net change is -1 - 1 = -2)

Since you can only change the sum by +2 and -2, then the starting sum must be even - an even number of incorrectly aligned tumblers need to exist at the start.

Since there are an even number of 1's, then your algorithm should always turn two 1's into 0's every move. There should never be a need to do any other move on a setup that started solvable.

Your algorithm should represent the tumblers as a list of bits like `tumblers = [0,1,1,0]`.
First, check solvability by summing the list and checking if even:
`solvable = (sum(tumblers)%2==0)`.
Only if it's solvable, set up a loop to solve:

```
if(solvable)
    while(sum(tumblers)!=0)
        found = 0
        indexA = null
        indexB = null
        foreach(tumblers as index=>tumbler)
            if(found==2)
                break //exit foreach loop since you found two 1's
            endif
            if(tumbler==1)
                found++
                if(indexA==null)
                    indexA = index
                else
                    indexB = index
                endif
            endif
        endforeach
        tumblers[indexA] = 0
        tumblers[indexB] = 0
    endwhile
endif
```